# mavg wavefront query timeout when called through the REST api

Tags: telegraf, wavefront-telegraf

I am running following [wavefront](https://www.wavefront.com/) query to get `SINGLE VALUE` which is *Average over the given time range* for which the query is being called. This works fine in the wavefront dashboard but it times out when called through the *Wavefront REST API*. Can this query be optimized so that it does not timeout or is there an issue running it through REST api:

```
mavg(1vw, avg(ts(telegraf.response.times.99.percentile , accountid="123" and env="prod" and myvar!="true”)))
```

I tried with following but does not help

```
mavg(1vw, avg(align(900s, mean, ts(telegraf.response.times.99.percentile , accountid=“123” and env=“prod” and myvar!=“true”))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some special character in place of `double quotes` that came in while copy-pasting the query. It worked fine when I typed the whole query manually.